# How to convert stdin socket to request socket in Dart?

Tags: sockets, dart, request, stdin

I am getting an error

> Unhandled exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'write' was called on null while sending the string to socket.write.

On the other hand if I connect stdin to the socket is perfectly working. In below code if you comment socket.write('$_request\r\n'); and uncomment the stdin.listen((data) => you will see everything is working as it should be.

The

```
String _request = "Hello World";
```

is hard coded, but it might come from over an internet or another client. I try to follow some example and can't understand why stdin.listen is work and not standard string.

So my question is How to convert stdin socket to request socket in Dart?

This is the working code help of @Gazi:

**UPDATED:**

```
Socket.connect("192.168.22.120", 3000)
          .then((Socket sock) {
    socket = sock;
    socket.listen(dataHandler,
            onError: errorHandler,
            onDone: doneHandler,
            cancelOnError: false);
  }).then((_) {
    print(_request); // so that your code runs AFTER the TCP/IP connection
    socket.write('$_request\r\n');
  })
  .catchError((AsyncError e) {
    print("Unable to connect: $e");
    exit(1);
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is your code, here's what's happening:

The code inside the `.then()` part is running later in time compared to the `socket.write()` below. `.then()` is assigning a callback function and moving on. Right after that `socket.write()` below is called. After that, once the TCP/IP connection is established, `socket = sock` is executed. So, your `socket` variable is not assigned when `socket.write()` is called.

Here's what happens with the stdin line: the `(data) => socket.write` code is executing after you click on the keyboard. This happens after the TCP/IP connection is established. Therefore your `socket` is assigned.

Here's what you should do instead:

```
  Socket.connect("192.168.22.120", 3000)
          .then((Socket sock) {
    socket = sock;
    socket.listen(dataHandler,
            onError: errorHandler,
            onDone: doneHandler,
            cancelOnError: false);
  }).then((_) {
    print(_request); // so that your code runs AFTER the TCP/IP connection
    socket.write('$_request\r\n');
  })
  .catchError((AsyncError e) {
    print("Unable to connect: $e");
    exit(1);
  });
```

so that your code runs AFTER the TCP/IP connection. If you use async/await, it would be even simpler.

Comment: I got this error: The argument type '() → dart.core::Null' can't be assigned to the parameter type '(dynamic) → dart.async::FutureOr<dynamic>'.
Try changing the type of the parameter, or casting the argument to '(dynamic) → dart.async::FutureOr<dynamic>'.
  }).then(() {

Comment: thanks, I add underscore. }).then((_) { and its working

Comment: Ok let me fix the code, sorry I had not tested it :)

Comment: its okay. this works inside main but doesn't work in Future. I open to new question, if you can contribute there I will appreciate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54479462/how-to-return-socket-data-from-future-in-dart