# How to return socket data from Future in Dart?

Tags: sockets, dart, return, future

Likely I send data to server and get data back even very big data using code below between =========== lines. This was to my experiment for I need to some intermediate solution so I can connect my Flutter app to tcp socket. For this I choose auqeduct.io. Today help from Gazi I found the solution to complete my code between =========== lines.

Because of I am using auqeduct their handle function look like this.

```
@override
  Future<RequestOrResponse> handle(Request request) async {
```

So, I try to modify my code and use Future to return socket data as string. I can get data using code below between =========== lines, but I cannot get any data using Future _handle(String _request) async.

_socket.listen((data) prints the data cannot assign data to string, so I cannot return string.

**works:** print("(1) $_secureResponse");

**not worked:** _secureResponse =  new String.fromCharCodes(data).trim();

If I don't use Future and put the code inside main() all is working perfectly.

***In my test server I send a "Hello World" and in return I get "Welcome Sir/Madam".***

My question is: How to return socket data from Future in Dart?

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert';

Socket socket;
String _errorData;
String _secureResponse;

void main() async {

  var _test = await _handle("Hello World");
  print("Print _test: $_test");

}


Future<String> _handle(String _request) async {
  print("Future Starts Here");
  print("Request: $_request");
    _errorData = "Server_Error";
    if (_request != null) {
      print("Request has data");
      // =============================================================
      Socket _socket;
      await Socket.connect("192.168.22.120", 3000).then((Socket sock) {
        _socket = sock;
        _socket.listen((data) {
          print("Socket start to listen to database");
          // GET FROM SERVER *********************
          _secureResponse =  new String.fromCharCodes(data).trim();
          print("(1) $_secureResponse");
        }, onError: ((error, StackTrace trace) {
          _secureResponse = _errorData;
          print("(2) $_secureResponse");
        }), onDone: ((){
          _socket.destroy();
          exit(0);
        }), cancelOnError: false);
      }).then((_) {
        print("Socket sends data to database");
        // SENT TO SERVER ************************
        _socket.write('$_request\r\n');
      }).catchError((AsyncError e) {
        _secureResponse = _errorData;
        print("(3) $_secureResponse");
        exit(1);
      });
      // ==============================================================
    } else {
      _secureResponse = _errorData;
      print("(4) $_secureResponse");
    }
  print("(6) $_secureResponse");
  print("Future Ends Here");
  return _secureResponse;
}
```

**Result:**

1. Future Starts Here
2. Request: "**Hello World**”
3. Request has data Socket sends data to database
4. (6) **null.**  --- **expected** return "*Welcome Sir/Madam*"
5. Future Ends Here
6. Print_test: **null**  --- **expected** return "*Welcome Sir/Madam*"
7. Socket start to listen to database
8. (1) "**Welcome Sir/Madam**”

Comment: Hi Nick, I find it hard to understand what you mean. Perhaps if you could also provide an alternative Result that says what you expected, that may help.

Comment: it must return okay in my server but  print("(6) $_secureResponse") is empty. also print test is empty

Comment: do you know any free eco testing site so I can use ip and port, so I can update my code to you to test it

Comment: I update the result on below, as you can see 4 stage and 6 stage prints null

Comment: Sorry I won't have time to test, I think if you edit your question to provide a full expected output it will be more clear.

Comment: okay I will update

Comment: Update the the question and show  expected return data look like

Comment: I'm sorry, still not clear. I don't see the `Print_test` in your code. I think you should provide two clear outputs: one that you currently see and one that you want to see, without any extra explanations that may wrongly be interpreted as output.

Comment: var _test = await _handle(“Hello World”);
  print("Print _test: $_test");

Comment: its in the main() section

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might work. I think you should read up about streams/futures/async/await, though.

```
Future<String> _handle(String _request) async {
  print("Future Starts Here");
  print("Request: $_request");
    _errorData = "Server_Error";
    if (_request != null) {
      print("Request has data");
      // =============================================================
      Socket _socket;
      await Socket.connect("192.168.22.120”, 3000).then((Socket sock) {
        _socket = sock;
      }).then((_) {
        print("Socket sends data to database");
        // SENT TO SERVER ************************
        _socket.write('$_request\r\n');
        return _socket.first;
      }).then((data) {
        print("Socket start to listen to database");
        // GET FROM SERVER *********************
        _secureResponse =  new String.fromCharCodes(data).trim();
        print("(1) $_secureResponse");
      }).catchError((AsyncError e) {
        _secureResponse = _errorData;
        print("(3) $_secureResponse");
        exit(1);
      });
      // ==============================================================
    } else {
      _secureResponse = _errorData;
      print("(4) $_secureResponse");
    }
  print("(6) $_secureResponse");
  print("Future Ends Here");
  return _secureResponse;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much. yes its working. I am very confuse about streams/futures/async/await. Looking good document with clear example. Any idea?

Comment: I didnt know I can use .then twice

Comment: Each then returns a Future, to which you can then once more. Using await is clearer, though. I do have a video of mine that you can watch, feel free to skip parts of it in the beginning in which I talk about flutter. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yyvTrXCDdYg
Also you can watch this other video that's a bit older: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MUDOIAssBDs
Also you can read these https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/futures https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/streams